# .hitTestPoint hitting multiple test points (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hittest

I can write a hitTestPoint trigger as such

```
if (mc1.hitTestPoint(mc2.x, mc2.y, true))
```

and if I want to have multiple test points I can write something like

```
if (mc1.hitTestPoint(mc2.x, mc2.y, true) || mc1.hitTestPoint(mc2.x-5, mc2.y, true) || mc1.hitTestPoint(mc2.x+5, mc2.y, true))
```

I am wondering though if there is anyway to define multiple hitpoints in the same statement. I've tried something like this with no luck...

```
if (mc1.hitTestPoint((mc2.x, mc2.y, true) || (mc2.x, mc2.y, true)))
```

or

```
if (mc1.hitTestPoint((mc2.x+5 || mc2.x-5), mc2.y, true))
```

...and many others but nothing seems to work. It is a pain to write the new points out for the same object over and over especially when you have 20+ hitpoint that you need to check for. Is there any way to add multiple points in one statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to confuse programming and witchery. DisplayObject.hitTestPoint accepts 2 to 3 arguments of designated types (Number, Number, [optional Boolean])  in this designated order, and nothing else.

> ((mc2.x, mc2.y, true) || (mc2.x, mc2.y, true)) = single Boolean argument
>
> ((mc2.x+5 || mc2.x-5), mc2.y, true)  = (Boolean, Number, Boolean)

So you hittest one point at a time. To hittest 20 of them you need to loop through an Array of points. For example:

```
var Foo:Array =
[
    mc2.x, mc2.y,
    mc2.x+5, mc2.y,
    mc2.x-5, mc2.y
];

// Hit test pairs of elements as (x,y) coordinates.
for (var i:int = 0; i < Foo.length; i += 2)
{
    var aHit:Boolean = mc1.hitTestPoint(Foo[i], Foo[i+1]);
    
    if (aHit)
    {
        trace("Hit!", Foo[i], Foo[i+1]);
    }
    else
    {
        trace("Miss!", Foo[i], Foo[i+1]);
    }
}
```